# How to use Mathematica to find the mode of a set of data?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

```
Mode[{2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10}]
```

Why can't the mode command be used to find the mode of a set of data?

Comment: Because that command/function does not exist. See [`Descriptive Statistics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalOperationsOnData.html#7135)

Comment: @BobHanlon But Mathematica display `Mode` in black like proper defined function, maybe this is what caused confusion.

Comment: From `?Mode`, "Mode is an option to Eliminate and related functions 
that specifies in what sense the equations are to be solved. The 
possible settings for Mode are Generic, Modular, and Rational."

Comment: @azerbajdzan According to my limited experience, nowadays this type of mistake is often a sign of ChatGPT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Commonest[{2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10}]
```

---

```
{9}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10};
```

```
Keys @ MaximalBy[Counts @ list, # &]
```

> {9}

```
{MaximalBy[SequenceCases[list, {a_ ..}], Length][[1, 1]]}
```

> {9}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10};
```

---

Using `Split` and `GroupBy`:

```
Last@GroupBy[Split[list], Length, Union @@ # &]
```

> `{9}`